# Haskell searching through a large textfile efficiently

Tags: performance, haskell, file

I have been given a list `xs` and a function `f`, and I want to know stuff like how many `x <- xs` satisfy `` (f x) `elem` xs `` or which ones do, etc. However, the problem is that the list `xs` is available only as an external file.

```
import Data.Char
import System.IO.Strict
import qualified Data.Set as Set

vowel x = elem x "aeiou"

toPigLatin :: String -> String
toPigLatin word
    | vowel (head word) = word ++ "ay"
    | not $ null [x | x <- word, vowel x] = let (v, c) = span (not.vowel) word in c ++ v ++ "ay"
    | otherwise = word


wordList = lines <$>  System.IO.Strict.readFile "toyWordSet"
wordSet = Set.fromList <$> wordList

good :: String -> IO Bool
good word = (Set.member (toPigLatin word)) <$> wordSet

mapMBool :: (a -> IO b) -> [a] -> IO [b]
mapMBool f l = do
                case l of
                    [] -> return []
                    (x:xs) -> do
                            b1 <- f x
                            bs <- mapMBool f xs
                            return (b1:bs)
```

Ultimately, I want to compute `wordList >>= mapMBool good`, which is a value of type `IO [Bool]` which have `True` at the positions where the desired property is satisfied.

Now, I have three main concerns:

1. When I run my code with a `toyWordSet`, it runs fine but I ultimately intend to replace it with `/usr/share/dict/words`, on which my PC freezes. How do I make my program more efficient?
2. Writing a function like `mapMBool` is not the most elegant idea ever. How can I do this more elegantly?
3. For some reason, I get some strange exceptions, when I try to use the lazy `readFile` instead of the strict version. What is happening? Why must I use strictness?

Other general comments on the coding style or practice is also welcome.

Comment: `mapMBool` is just `mapM`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you've missed the forest for the trees. While the origin of your list might be `IO`, there's no need to carry values around inside the `IO` monad just because that's where you found them.

Write your functions as though the external world doesn't exist. E.g.—

```
-- Was `good`
pigExists :: String -> Set String -> Bool
pigExists word set = Set.member (toPigLatin word) set
```

Write your actions to set up the values you need to use your `IO`-ignorant functions. E.g.—

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
    allWords <- words <$> readFile "wherever" -- equivalent to `allWords <- wordList`
    let pigHits = map (\word -> pigExists word (Set.fromList allWords)) allWords
    print $ length $ filter id pigHits -- Or some other IO action that does what you need
```

When in doubt, parameterize. You tripped yourself up by defining `wordSet` directly on `wordList` instead of just accepting any `[String]` value you're passed.

Comment: This solves the problem of getting frozen, but for a file with 45k words, this still takes forever ( > 30 minutes)

Comment: Hm... that is wildly excessive. You're running from GHCi, aren't you? Try compiling it. Running my compiled version on a 45k word file takes my machine 0.097s.

Comment: I did. It does not seem to help at all. Can I see your code? Here is mine: https://pastebin.com/qzeFri4H

Comment: Humm... there's something strange going on. Change your last line to `mapM_ putStrLn pigHits`. Now change it to `putStrLn $ unlines pigHits`. The former finishes immediately for me, the latter runs until my patience is exceeded (so, longer than 15 seconds). I have no idea what's happening! How exciting. Try posting it as a mystery to Stack Overflow.

Comment: That works. Thanks. I also tried `sequence_ $ map putStrLn pigHits`. That works too